# Jquery trigger unblocked hover when mouse over the element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, hover

Is it even possible?

I used hover-block system with element id check to prevent false animations/actions when user moving mouse alot and elements taking wrong places. Now all works fine, but if i'm hovering one element and triggering his animation and other stuff, i can't just hover-out him and get my mouse over another element and trigger his hover animation in time when new hover will be unblocked. So it takes actions like leave element and hover him again, to finally trigger that new animation. Sorry for bad english and explanation.

http://jsfiddle.net/LFcgm/1/

Example of hover-out unblocking.

```
function() {
        console.log("hoverout " + hoveredElementID);
        if (hoveredElementID === $(this).attr('id')) {
            var $this = $(this);
            var t = setTimeout(function() {
                hovered = 0;
                console.log(hovered + "leaved");
                $this.css({'-webkit-transform' : 'rotate(' + angle + 'deg)'});
                $this.css({'left' : currentLeft + 'px', 'top' : currentTop + 'px', 'z-index' : currentZindex});
                $this.removeClass('focusedPic').off('click');
                hoveredElementID = "";
            }, 300);
            $(this).data('timeout', t);
        }
```

Comment: can't you use mouseenter and mouseleave events? hover is called on every single pixel mouse move

Comment: I think Kamil is mixing up the concept of a mouse "hover" and jQuery's ".hover()", which is just a convenience method for quickly binding two callbacks to mouseenter and mouseleave. Your usage of hover (in the fiddle provided) is the same thing as he suggested (and also, it's not called on every single pixel mouse move, as stated...)

Comment: Yeah, i fount out it today, when my head was clear. Anyway, thank you.